# dynamic svg in html5

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dynamic

I expected SVG nodes to be first class citizen in html5 but I get an unexpected behavior (under Firefox 55.0.2 and Chrome 54.0.2840.71).

In the following html file, I expect a big circle to be dynamically added to a newly created svg element. Instead :

- The Inspector tells me the DOM was correctly modified
- Nothing is displayed
- when I copy paste the DOM (copy -> outer HTML, script deleted) in a new file, the resulting static html file is perfectly fine.

What do I miss ? Why do I have this discrepancy between the DOM and the rendered version of it ? How can I correct this ? re-draw ?

When I use NS suffixed versions of functions (ie. createElementNS and setAttributeNS) I get similar results and nothing is rendered.

Here is the culprit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>bug dynamic svg</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
Element.prototype.grow = function (tag, attribute_map) {
    var child = document.createElement(tag);
    if ( attribute_map !== undefined ) {
        for (let key in attribute_map) {
            child.setAttribute(key, attribute_map[key]);
        }
    }
    this.appendChild(child);
    return child;
};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sandbox"><svg viewbox="0 0 200 200"></svg></div>
<script>
var g_svg = document.getElementById("sandbox").firstElementChild;
g_svg.grow('circle', {'cx':"100", 'cy':"100", 'r':"32"});
</script>
</html>
```

and here is the DOM-copy-pasted result I get via the inspector (script removed manually) :

```
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>bug dynamic svg</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sandbox"><svg viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="32"></circle></svg></div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements go in the SVG namespace, attributes usually don't.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>bug dynamic svg</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
Element.prototype.grow = function (tag, attribute_map) {
    var child = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    if ( attribute_map !== undefined ) {
        for (let key in attribute_map) {
            child.setAttribute(key, attribute_map[key]);
        }
    }
    this.appendChild(child);
    return child;
};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sandbox"><svg viewbox="0 0 200 200"></svg></div>
<script>
var g_svg = document.getElementById("sandbox").firstElementChild;
g_svg.grow('circle', {'cx':"100", 'cy':"100", 'r':"32"});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: indeed... namespaced attributes are for 'xml:space' kind of attributes... I knew it ! But I missed it... Thank you very much ^3^